# What does the word 「とまあ」mean?

Tags: words, manga

It is said by a boy who has just finished talking about his plan to a group of little kids. Here is the sentence.

**とまあ** ざっとこんなところだが　どうだみんな！

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means somethng like "So, ~~" used when trying to wrap up a convo or explanation.  It is mostly an attention-drawer than a meaningful phrase.

The 「と」 is, believe it or not, a quotative particle used to refer to the over-all content of the speaker's statement that is now ending.